# Delete partitions from external table hive in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

How to delete partitions when inserting into an external table, if such a partition is not in the `dataframe`?

For example.
External table has partition with name `report_date=2021-01-31`. I want to insert data with one row `report_date` and value `2022-01-31`. How can I delete partition `report_date=2021-01-31` using spark?